# meteor, mongodb, spacebars, how do I display only 2 decimal places

Tags: mongodb, meteor, spacebars

I have a collection that has values like `{ "pctFail" : "0.3515500159795462" }` and when I pass this to a template and display as {{myTemplate}}% it displays in my html as 0.3515500159795462%.  How do I display this as 0.35% ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could override the data context's property with a template helper method:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  pctFail: function () { return this.pctFail.toFixed(2); }
})
```

And then use `{{pctFail}}%` as before. If you insist on storing the numerical property as a string, you'll need to return something like `parseFloat(this.pctFail).toFixed(2)` instead.

Comment: Thanks Donny, I have several items in my collection that I want to apply this .toFixed(2) function to.  My current helper just returns them all in a `return Items.find()` sort of fashion and then I iterate over all of them with a block helper {{#each items}} sort of fashion.  Is there a way I can apply to all of the return values which are double values?  like `return Wafers.find().toFixed(2)` or do I have to create a helper for each one of my keys which are of this 'pct' type?

Comment: Ok, I just made a method for each of my items (i.e. 'pctFail', 'pctX', 'pctY', etc.) just being generic here but I had 7 data items that were in pct which I needed to convert to a 2 decimal fixed precision.  I wanted something general which would handle everything, but creating 7 helper methods wasn't bad.  Thanks again Donny!

Comment: could you please share your code? I have the same issue, but I do not get it how to apply this answer to Items.find()

Answer (score 1):

You can also solve this problem by using a helper function http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper which can be used from all templates like so:

```
Template.registerHelper('toFixed', function (x, decimals) {
    return x.toFixed(decimals);
})
```

and then you can use:

```
 {{toFixed item.pctFail 2}}
```

If you insist on storing the numerical property as a string, you'll need to return something like

```
parseFloat(x).toFixed(decimals)
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this using substrings

```
Template,myTemplate.helpers({
    pctFail: function () {
        return this.pctFail.substring(0, 4);
    }
)};
```