# How to subtract two date time in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate, mlab

I have used aggregate function.

```
db.checkins.aggregate([
       {$match: {checkinType: "Beacon",
               "associationIds.organizationId":"af39bc69-1938-4149",
               "checkinData.time": {"$gte": new Date("2018-01-18T18:30:00.000Z"), 
                                   "$lt": new Date("2018-01-19T18:30:00.000Z")}
                }
        },
       {"$sort":{"checkinData.time":-1}},
       {$group: {"_id":
                    {"orgId":"$asst.organizationId", "userId":"$asst.userId"},
                    "lastSeen":{"$first":"$checkinData.time"},
                   "firstSeen":{"$last":"$checkinData.time"},
               }
       }, 
      {"$project":{"_id":1,"lastSeen":1, "firstSeen":1, 
                  totalHourSpent:{$subtract: ["$lastSeen","$firstSeen"]}}}, 
  ])
```

> When I performed this Query mongo return **totalHourSpent** in milisecond which is given below.

```
{
  "_id" : {
        "orgId" : "af39bc69-1938-4149-b9f7-f101fd9baf73",
        "userId" : "34adb4a0-0012-11e7-bf32-cf79d6b423e9"
  },
 "lastSeen" : ISODate("2018-01-19T18:49:52.242+05:30"),
 "firstSeen" : ISODate("2018-01-19T10:08:21.026+05:30"),
 "totalHourSpent" : NumberLong("31291216")
},
{
  "_id" : {
       "orgId" : "af39bc69-1938-4149-b9f7-f101fd9baf73",
       "userId" : "679416b0-3f88-11e7-8d27-77235eb1ba9b"
   },
   "lastSeen" : ISODate("2018-01-19T20:51:30.946+05:30"),
   "firstSeen" : ISODate("2018-01-19T11:07:44.256+05:30"),
   "totalHourSpent" : NumberLong("35026690")
 },
```

> How to calculate **totalHourSpent** in hour. Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) to view all date functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to 2 decimal places using MongoDB aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482623/rounding-to-2-decimal-places-using-mongodb-aggregation-framework)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

$subtract gives you the duration in millisecond. So we need to divide the duration with 3600000 for hour format.

The returned mills can be converted to hour by dividing by 3600000 (number of milliseconds in 1 hour):

```
totalHourSpent:{$divide : [{$subtract: ["$lastSeen","$firstSeen"]}, 3600000]}
```

ie

```
35026690÷3600000=9.72963611111111 hours
```

Comment: How to get value after two decimal number. Thanks!

Comment: If you care about precision, you might need to use extended bson types for example `$numberDecimal`

Comment: I wanna get like 9.729 hours

Comment: From Mongdb 4.2 onwards can use  $trunc  operator, syntax { $trunc : [ <number>, <place> ] } with aggregation, see the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038444/how-to-truncate-a-number-to-3-decimals

Answer (score 0):

**group, count, avg**

subtract value return in milliseconds

```
  const avgTime = await Post.aggregate<{
    count?: string;
    avg_time: string;
  }>([
    {
      $match: {
        finishedAt: {
          $exists: true,
        },
      },
    },

    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: {
          $sum: 1,
        },
        avg_time: {
          $avg: {
            // $subtract: [
            //   {
            //     $ifNull: ['$finishedAt', 0],
            //   },
            //   {
            //     $ifNull: ['$createdAt', 0],
            //   },
            // ],
            $subtract: ['$finishedAt', '$createdAt'],
            //$subtract: [{ $toDate: '$finishedAt' }, { $toDate: '$createdAt' }],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ]);
```

for more info

[https://database.guide/mongodb-subtract/#:~:text=In%20MongoDB%2C%20you%20can%20use,and%20return%20the%20resulting%20date](https://database.guide/mongodb-subtract/#:%7E:text=In%20MongoDB%2C%20you%20can%20use,and%20return%20the%20resulting%20date)