# Get Time duration of two dates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to execute query in MongoDB Time duration between two dates
Lets say

**        startTime: ISODate('2019-09-17 20:15:00.000'),
        endTime: ISODate('2019-09-17 20:55:00.000') **

I want lastSeen-firstSeen as a duration in the output

Below is the query IM executing

```
db.TN_Collection.aggregate([
        {$match: {DE:{$in:devices},'T':{$gt: ISODate('2019-09-15 21:45:00.000'), $lt: ISODate('2019-09-15 22:25:00.000')}}},
        {$group: {_id: {A: '$A', DE: '$DE'}, firstSeen:{$min:'$T'}, lastSeen: {$max: '$T'}}}
])
.forEach(function(msg) {print(msg._id.A +',' + msg._id.DE+',' + msg.firstSeen+',' + msg.lastSeen)})
```

Comment: what do you mean by time duration ? Can you provide sample docs & expected o/p. & what was the issue with the existing query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract two date time in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369419/how-to-subtract-two-date-time-in-mongodb)

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma I've start time and end time.
I've used $min and $max function to get first and last seen of 'A' against DE' present in my documents.
after getting first seen and last seen I want total duration of A i.e lastseen-firstseen

`eg. firstSeen: ISODate('2019-09-15 21:45:00.000')`
`lastSeen: ISODate('2019-09-15 22:25:00.000')`
I want ouput **lastSeen-firstSeen** ie.
40 minutes.

I hope  this will help @srinivasy

Comment: @Mr.S.Sharma  Using above query I'm getting outputs as `A: 1234, DE: 921, FirstSeen: ISODate('2019-09-15 21:45:00.000'),  lastSeen: ISODate('2019-09-15 22:25:00.000')` Instead of firstSeen and lastSeen in my output I simply want subtract of these two dates ie **Duration**`

Answer (score 0):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.TN_Collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "DE":{
                $in:["76612"]
            },
            "T":{
                $gte:ISODate('2019-09-11 07:20:55.298'),
                $lte:ISODate('2019-09-15 22:25:00.000')
            }
        }   
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "A":"$A",
                "DE":"$DE"
            },
            "firstSeen":{
                $min:"$T"
            },
            "lastSeen":{
                $max:"$T"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0,
            "A":"$_id.A",
            "DE":"$_id.DE",
            "Duration":{
                $divide:[
                    {
                        $subtract:[
                            "$lastSeen",
                            "$firstSeen"
                        ]
                    },
                    60000
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9b306b711a1e3a8167c712"),
    "DE" : "76612",
    "A" : "00101219",
    "T" : ISODate("2019-09-11T07:20:55.298Z"),
    "R" : -58
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9b306b711a1e3a8167c713"),
    "DE" : "76612",
    "A" : "00101208",
    "T" : ISODate("2019-09-11T07:20:55.298Z"),
    "R" : -64
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9b306b711a1e3a8167c714"),
    "DE" : "76612",
    "A" : "00100005",
    "T" : ISODate("2019-09-11T07:20:55.298Z"),
    "R" : -70
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9b306b711a1e3a8167c715"),
    "DE" : "76612",
    "A" : "00101219",
    "T" : ISODate("2019-09-12T07:20:55.298Z"),
    "R" : -58
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9b306b711a1e3a8167c716"),
    "DE" : "76612",
    "A" : "00101208",
    "T" : ISODate("2019-09-13T07:20:55.298Z"),
    "R" : -64
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9b306b711a1e3a8167c717"),
    "DE" : "76612",
    "A" : "00100005",
    "T" : ISODate("2019-09-14T07:20:55.298Z"),
    "R" : -70
}
```

**Output:**

```
{ "A" : "00100005", "DE" : "76612", "Duration" : 4320 }
{ "A" : "00101208", "DE" : "76612", "Duration" : 2880 }
{ "A" : "00101219", "DE" : "76612", "Duration" : 1440 }
```

Comment: Thankyou for sharing this. please check this error after executing query `2019-10-07T07:41:47.325+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @stack.js:7:12

failed to load: stack.js`

Comment: `assert: command failed: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "invalid operator '$toString'", "code" : 15999 } : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:287:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
@ss.js:2:1`

Comment: which mongo version are you using?

Comment: MongoDB shell version: 3.2.9

Comment: Is it fine if response comes like this: `{ "A" : "a", "DE" : "phone", "Duration" : 40 }` instead of `{ "A" : "a", "DE" : "phone", "Duration" : "40 minutes" }`?

Comment: Sure .
Thanks for your help

Comment: @rajatsingh Updated the query accordingly.

Comment: Can you please post sample data on which you are testing this query?

Comment: `00502251,75579,Sun Sep 15 2019 22:24:52 GMT+0000 (UTC),Sun Sep 15 2019 22:24:57 GMT+0000 (UTC)`

Comment: This is the output I'm getting after executing the query that Ive mention in my question box
Instead of firstSeen and lastSen I want total duration. i.e lastSeen - firstSeen

Comment: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d78a4b99eb772135951f376"), "DE" : "76612", "A" : "00101219", "T" : ISODate("2019-09-11T07:20:55.298Z"), "R" : -58 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d78a4b99eb772135951f377"), "DE" : "76612", "A" : "00101208", "T" : ISODate("2019-09-11T07:20:55.298Z"), "R" : -64 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d78a4b99eb772135951f379"), "DE" : "76612", "A" : "00100005", "T" : ISODate("2019-09-11T07:20:55.298Z"), "R" : -70 }`

Comment: this is the sample data. Ignore date on this particular sample data . these dates already have in my mongo db for which I'm looking for duration

Comment: @rajatsingh The query seems fine. I have added sample data and output... Please cross-check the range you are specifying in the query.

Comment: I dont know why still its not working in my case. As I've used correct Time Stamp.

Comment: Anyways thanks for helping me out on this. I'll investigate further

Comment: @rajatsingh Also let me know when you find the cause :)

Comment: Can we get duration without using $project ?

Comment: Can we discuss problem over a call because I believe  there is some communication problem for explaining the situation.